# Check if binary was compiled with security checks (/GS)

Tags: windows, tools, binary-analysis, software-security, stack-variables

I have to check massive amount of binaries whether they were compiled with the `/GS` option. I assume a good indicator would be to check if they have stack cookie or not. Do you know any tool that can do this, or any tool that I could build into a script, so I don't have to do it manually?

### Edit

[Found](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee672187.aspx) [Binscope](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44995), I'll check if it's capable to check more binaries at the same time or it's scriptable.

### Edit2

It requires debug symbols, so this is not a solution.

### Edit3

https://github.com/NetSPI/PEchecker

Comment: Do you have the private debug symbols (.pdb) for the binaries? If not, BinScope won't help.

Comment: I noticed it. I just checked it and it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you can check the [`IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY`](http://mingw-w64.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0-1/ntimage_8h_source.html#l00107) structure, it has a field for the pointer to `SecurityCookie`'s value in the image.
2. In very old binaries, this structure might be not used, or `SecurityCookie` RVA is 0 even though the binary may be using `/GS`. In such case you can scan for the characteristic code signature of the `@__security_check_cookie@4` function:

   ```
   3B0D........7501C3E9 (VC7)  
   3B0D........0F85........C3 (VC7?)  
   3B0D........7502F3C3E9 (VC8+)
   ```
3. you can also scan for the initial cookie value (`BB40E64E`) in the binary. Though I guess this might produce some false positives.

Comment: You can also search for byte string `68 09 04 00 C0`, which is `push 0xC0000409` (`push STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`), used by library function `__report_gsfailure`. However, as with @igor-skochinsky's third suggestion above, this may cause FPs, so best to use in conjunction with @igor-skochinsky's other suggestions too.

Comment: @JasonGeffner: an old VC7 binary I have here doesn't have that byte sequence - it doesn't raise the exception but only shows a fatal messagebox.

Comment: OK, my comment above may cause FPs *and* FNs ;)